# Inner query - last date clause

Tags: trigger, soql, conditional

I have a trigger on `after Insert` and `after update` on `Contact`.
This trigger updates `Account.SalatySumLastContactsLast`, with sum of `Contact.Salary` where `Contact.mydate__c` is latest.
I simplified the logic for the question, I have to use trigger.

How can I wrote the query to select only contacts with `contact.mydate__c` is the latest.

```
SELECT id,(SELECT id FROM Contacts WHERE myDate ... ) from Account
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SOQL help with subquery where clause](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/53249/soql-help-with-subquery-where-clause)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can order by `mydate__c` to get the contact where `mydate__c`  is latest.

```
SELECT Id,(SELECT Id FROM Contacts ORDER BY mydate__c DESC LIMIT 1) FROM Account
```

updated Code:

```
map<String,Date> latestDateMap=new map<String,Date>();
for(Account acc : [SELECT Id,RollupSummary__c FROM Account /*WHERE Your filter*/]){
 latestDateMap.put(acc.Id,acc.RollupSummary__c );
}

List<Contact> conList=[SELECT Id FROM Contact WHERE AccountId IN :latestDateMap.keySet() AND mydate__c IN :latestDateMap.values()];
```

Comment: Thanks but I can have more than one contact with the same mydate__c which is latest

Comment: What do you mean by latest here. Is is today's date, yesterday or N no of days?

Comment: It is a custom date field, it can be yesterday , today , even tomorrow. In this case I want to take all Contacts where Contact.MyDate == tomorrow.

Comment: What you can do is create a Roll-Up field on Account object to get the max/latest mydate__c  for the number of Contacts added to it, then loop over Account to get the AccountId and latest date(rollup summary) and based on that fetch all the contact. I have  updated code example in answer above.